# How does PacketZoom work?

Tags: android, http, networking, java-native-interface, httpurlconnection

I want to track all HTTP requests from my android app (including the requests made by libraries used in the app), by just adding some kind of interceptor. But it isn't obvious how should I do it. Here is a SDK which claims that it does optimisations on network requests, so you just have to add it to your project and it automatically captures all http requests and optimises them. 
https://packetzoom.com/index.html?utm_expid=79277288-12.gxkHaG0PSAG0KVsLa3JdzA.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fpacketzoom.com%2F

How does it work? If they implemented their functionality of optimisations then it means all HTTP requests are somehow trackable. I guess they've done it through JNI, but I fail to find any working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Packetzoom engineer is here. 
There are few approaches to intercepting all requests from the app:

1. You implement local http proxy server which can run as separate service
   and use [ProxySelector.setDefault API](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ProxySelector.html) to redirect all requests to your proxy. This generally works well with popular libraries like **OkHttp** and **HttpUrlConnection**.
   However, you won't be able to see https traffic since it's encrypted and your proxy has to support `HTTP CONNECT` method to provide a tunnel for https.
2. The second approach is to use [URLStreamHandlerFactory API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLStreamHandlerFactory.html).

to register custom HTTP/HTTPS protocol handlers. This approach is limited to work only with HttpUrlConnection API but you can get access to original HTTPS requests.

By the way, PacketZoom is now offering free HttpOptimizer service which monitors the performance of all your requests and also dynamically applies proper config parameters for your HTTP client (like timeouts, concurrency, cache) based on network type, location, carrier. You also have visibility to all traffic from 3rd party SDK and how much data they consume.